# Paypal SDK set billing plan to active

Tags: java, sdk, paypal-sandbox, billing

I am new to the PayPal SDK and I am trying to create a billing plan and change its status to ACTIVE. I have tried some sample Java code from the SDK tutorial but I can't get that code to work. Status remains CREATED. The code I tried can be found below.

What is missing/wrong?

The output from running the code is

```
Created plan with id = P-1MT21723NA428154CRJGOTXQ
Plan state = CREATED
Plan state = CREATED
```

Best regards /Lasse

```
// Build Plan object
Plan plan = new Plan();
plan.setName("T-Shirt of the Month Club Plan");
plan.setDescription("Template creation.");
plan.setType("fixed");

// Payment_definitions
PaymentDefinition paymentDefinition = new PaymentDefinition();
paymentDefinition.setName("Regular Payments");
paymentDefinition.setType("REGULAR");
paymentDefinition.setFrequency("MONTH");
paymentDefinition.setFrequencyInterval("1");
paymentDefinition.setCycles("12");

// Currency
Currency currency = new Currency();
currency.setCurrency("USD");
currency.setValue("20");
paymentDefinition.setAmount(currency);

// Charge_models
ChargeModels chargeModels = new ChargeModels();
chargeModels.setType("SHIPPING");
chargeModels.setAmount(currency);
List<ChargeModels> chargeModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
chargeModelsList.add(chargeModels);
paymentDefinition.setChargeModels(chargeModelsList);

// Payment_definition
List<PaymentDefinition> paymentDefinitionList = new ArrayList<>();
paymentDefinitionList.add(paymentDefinition);
plan.setPaymentDefinitions(paymentDefinitionList);

// Merchant_preferences
MerchantPreferences merchantPreferences = new MerchantPreferences();
merchantPreferences.setSetupFee(currency);
merchantPreferences.setCancelUrl("https://example.com/cancel");
merchantPreferences.setReturnUrl("https://example.com/return");
merchantPreferences.setMaxFailAttempts("0");
merchantPreferences.setAutoBillAmount("YES");
merchantPreferences.setInitialFailAmountAction("CONTINUE");
plan.setMerchantPreferences(merchantPreferences);

// Create payment
Plan createdPlan = plan.create(apiContext);
System.out.println("Created plan with id = " + createdPlan.getId());
System.out.println("Plan state = " + createdPlan.getState());

// Set up plan activate PATCH request
List<Patch> patchRequestList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("state", "ACTIVE");

// Create update object to activate plan
Patch patch = new Patch();
patch.setPath("/");
patch.setValue(value);
patch.setOp("replace");
patchRequestList.add(patch);

// Activate plan
createdPlan.update(apiContext, patchRequestList);
System.out.println("Plan state = " + createdPlan.getState());
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I had to execute Plan.get(context, createdPlan.getId());
to get the latest state of the plan.